# the background is not covering the whole area

Tags: html, css

take a look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scyxC/) . as you can see, the height of the left and right div are not the same with the height of the center div. How can I extend the side divs and make the height as the same as the center div? I tried using height:100%; but I did not get the result that I wanted.

my HTML :

```
<div id="left">
    dfsfdsf
</div>
<div id="center">
fldskjflsjfls
    <br/>gdfgdfg
</div>
<div id="right">
fdsflsdf    
</div>
```

my CSS :

```
#left {float:left;width:100px;background:blue;}
#center {float:left;width:100px;background:purple;}
#right {float:left;width:100px;background:green;}
```

Comment: The easy way is to put a `height:--px`in each div

Comment: I do not want to do that. because the results are dynamic.

Comment: Use `min-height` and possibly `max-height` if needed? (http://jsfiddle.net/scyxC/3/)

Comment: If you want a dynamic height, then table-cell (answer below) will work best I think.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of floating the divs you can alternatively use `display: table-cell;` so that the heights are uniform regardless their content.

http://jsfiddle.net/scyxC/2/

```
#left {display: table-cell;width:100px;background:blue;}
#center {display: table-cell;width:100px;background:purple;}
#right {display: table-cell;width:100px;background:green;}
```

Comment: Its supported [from IE8 onwards](http://caniuse.com/css-table) and in all other major browsers.

Answer (score 1):

You can either specify a height for each div, or set them to be 100% and put them in a container div:
Here's my modification to your fiddle:

[Modification to Your jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scyxC/1/)

```
<div style="height: 100px;">
<div id="left" style="height: 100%;">
    dfsfdsf
</div>
<div id="center" style="height: 100%;">
    fldskjflsjfls
    <br/>gdfgdfg
</div>
<div id="right" style="height: 100%;">
    fdsflsdf    
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason of this uneven height is due to the amount of content you put in. Either you can specify a maximum height of each div or use `display:table-cell;` as suggested by Adrift like this:-

```
#left {display: table-cell;.....................}
#center {display: table-cell;........................}
#right {display: table-cell;..............................}
```

Comment: Seems wrong to just copy-and-paste another poster's answer doesn't it?

Comment: @John Oh...Really ? If someone ask "Where is Spain" ? One person replies its Europe. I also provide the same answer. Is that copy-paste ?

Comment: For this question there were only 2-3 effective solution(which i know) out of which i suggested one. "display:table-cell" thing was known to me before also.